# Return a ctypes C struct back to C

Tags: python, c, ctypes, python-embedding

I'm trying to wrap my head around the ctypes API. I have a C structure (zmsg_t) I wish to create in Python and then return from Python to C.

So a Python method is called from C and needs to return an object which we then process in C again.

I have a binding to access and create the C methods and structures so in Python I can call the Zmsg() constructor. I now need to return this.

My python test method is simply:

```
def actor_test(*args, **kwargs):
    print("test")
    msg = Zmsg()
    frame = Zframe(b"Hello", 5)
    msg.prepend(frame)
    return msg
```

the method is called from C as follows:

`PyObject *pReturn = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);`

This correctly calls the method. However the returned object is of course a PyObject*. The debugger says it's

```
"<czmq._czmq_ctypes.Zmsg object at 0x7ffff5f18e50>"    PyObject
            [class]    "<class 'czmq._czmq_ctypes.Zmsg'>"   
            [super class]    "<class 'object'>"   
            [meta type]    "<class 'type'>"   
            ob_refcnt    1    Py_ssize_t
```

How I can I get it back to the original C type (zmsg_t *)

Any help really appreciated.

The ctypes definitions for Zmsg can be seen [here](https://github.com/zeromq/czmq/blob/d6283985ba52fd8c3f8fbdc7cd5c08372ff69ca1/bindings/python/czmq/_czmq_ctypes.py#L4392)

Answer (score 1):

I would try using `return byref(msg)` and do some C casting and watch out for garbage-collection. But tbh I am usually calling c from a python process.

Comment: If I do `return byref(msg._as_parameter_)` I receive a NULL pointer. It messes things up, guess that's the GC?

Comment: To prevent GC you need to keep a reference of the object in the python scope but i am not familiar with how memory is handled in python when it is embedded in another application.
to be sure and if you have the possibillity you could just allocate it in c.
ps: I could not find what that '_as_parameter_' does but I saw 'msg.c_address()' is supposed to return the address in C. i would have to read some of the python docs myself.
https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question as I was pointed by the python mailinglist to the fact that this question approaches it wrongly. It mixes both the ctypes API and the CPython API. Best is to use one approach. Since to embed Python you need the CPython API best is to use the CPython API to wrap to C methods. That way the when Python returns you'll endup with your own defined Python object in C and can access its internal structure.

[This tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes_tutorial.html) describes in detail how to wrap a C struct to a Python object.